# AWS EMR: Cluster terminated in user request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I'm trying to create new / clone existing cluster through AWS console in US West region. Cluster starts to creating but then, after 1 min (or even less), it starts to terminate itself, giving the error :

> Terminated by user request.

I tried to choose different region - same problem.

Can it be any restriction / key-pair / security group issue? It worked fine before, and I was able to create clusters without any issues using same key-pair and security group I have right now.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Auto-terminate is on, so while cloning/creating new cluster please make sure that the `Auto-terminate` checkbox is unchecked.

[image]